# Powershell New-EventLog Problems

Tags: powershell

Having issues creating a log file for my homework assignment. Most of the issues come when I start trying to create a new log file. Errors with the log file not being found and the source already is being used ect. ect.

Please Help! :)

Here is my assignment instructions:

1. Add a new provider/source to the Application log called MyLesson12
2. Add a new event to the Application log using the new provider
3. List the events in the Application log that are from the new provider
4. Create a new log called Lesson12Events and a provider called me
5. Add a 3 new events to the Lesson12Events
6. List the events, using a foreach loop and whatever properties you want, in the Lesson12Events log
7. Clear all events from the Lesson12Events log
8. List the events in the Lesson12Events log
9. Remove the Lesson12Events log

enter code here

```
New-EventLog Application -Source Lesson12a
Write-EventLog Application -Message "THIS TEST"  Lesson12a -EventId 0001
Write-EventLog Application -Message "THIS TEST2" Lesson12a -EventId 0002
Get-EventLog Application -Source Lesson12a
Remove-EventLog -Source Lesson12a
Read-Host "PAUSE"

New-EventLog MyLesson12 
Read-Host "PAUSE"
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu1  -Source ME -EventId 0001
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu2 -Source ME -EventId 0002
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu3 -Source ME -EventId 0003
$events = Get-EventLog MyLesson12 -Newest 50 | Sort-Object Index
foreach ($element in $events )
{
    $id = $element.Index.ToString()
    $source = $element.Source.ToString()
    $message = $element.Message.ToString()

    Write-Host "$id `t $source `t`t $message"
}
Clear-EventLog -LogName MyLesson12
Get-EventLog MyLesson12
Remove-EventLog MyLesson12
```

Comment: where do you get the errors? post them here along with your powershell version

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what happen but I was able to resolve my issues.

```
<#New-EventLog Application -Source Lesson12a
Write-EventLog Application -Message "THIS TEST"  Lesson12a -EventId 0001
Write-EventLog Application -Message "THIS TEST2" Lesson12a -EventId 0002
Get-EventLog Application -Source Lesson12a
Remove-EventLog -Source Lesson12a
Read-Host "PAUSE"#>

New-EventLog MyLesson12 -Source ME
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu1  -Source ME -EventId 0001
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu2 -Source ME -EventId 0002
Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message tutu3 -Source ME -EventId 0003
$events = Get-EventLog MyLesson12 -Newest 50 | Sort-Object Index
foreach ($element in $events )
{
 $id = $element.Index
 $source = $element.Source
 $message = $element.Message

 Write-Host "$id `t $source `t`t $message"
}
Clear-EventLog -LogName MyLesson12 
#Write-EventLog MyLesson12 -Message 'Logs Cleared'  -Source ME -EventId 1111
Get-EventLog MyLesson12
Remove-EventLog MyLesson12
#Remove-EventLog -Source ME
```